# Delete file with boot permission issue

Tags: boot, 18.04

I can not delete a file with boot permission?

```
Error removing file /home/tbone/Downloads/debian-9.6.0-amd64-netinstiso/boot: Permission denied
```

Comment: did you use sudo?

Comment: That is, type sudo rm home/tbone/Downloads/debian-9.6.0-amd64-netinstiso/boot`, and, when prompted, enter your login password (which won't be echoed).

Comment: Do you mean `root permission` ?

Comment: Like @waltinator says but with code blocks, open the terminal using `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` and type: `sudo rm /home/tbone/Downloads/debian-9.6.0-amd64-netinstiso/boot`